# Is it possible to redirect a file, that is downloaded using Subprocess.popen, to another directory?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to set up an `AWS Lambda` function that makes an `API` call using a jar file using python.

The code is shown below:

```
command_line = ('java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.getReport' + " " + arg1 + ", " + arg2 + ", " + arg3 + ", " + arg4 + ", " + arg5 + ", " + arg6)
args = shlex.split(command_line)
print(args)
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
```

This file (a text file that is compressed in gzip format) is downloaded into the same directory as the one holding the jar file and the properties file on my local machine. On AWS Lambda, this same code snippet executes successfully but gives an error:

> Cannot save file. Make sure you have enough space and have write access to the current directory.

Is this because AWS Lambda does not give access to download files anywhere but the `/tmp` folder?

What changes can I make to the code in order to download the file into the AWS Lambda `/tmp` folder instead of the folder holding the jar file?

I already tried changing the directory using os.chdir to the directory holding the jar file and going back to the parent directory after the subprocess command has processed but it downloads the file into the same directory as the one holding the jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to modify the jar tool to accept an output path. If that is not possible,

1. Copy the jar file to /tmp/ (or specify absolute path if that is possible)
2. In python script use os.chdir to change working dir to /tmp/ before calling Popen OR you can use 'cwd' parameter of Popen to run the command in /tmp

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar with json and xlsx file.

```
import uuid
data = {}
file_name = "test"
download_json_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), file_name))
with open(download_json_path, 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json.dumps({'data': data}, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Also you can copy the files in S3 using boto3 `s3` resource